# Speeding up square sample summing over image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, convolution

I am attempting to create a 2D array from another, by taking the sum of NxN pixels around a point on the image, and saving the result at the same coordinate in the new image:

```py
def sum_black(image: np.ndarray, size=11) -> np.ndarray:
    assert(size % 2)
    pad = (size - 1) // 2
    iH, iW = image.shape[:2]
    image = ((255 - image) / 255).astype(np.float32)
    image = cv.copyMakeBorder(image, pad, pad, pad, pad, cv.BORDER_CONSTANT, None, 0)
    output = np.zeros((iH, iW), dtype="float32")

    for y in range(iH):
        for x in range(iW):
            output[y, x] = image[y-pad:y+pad, x-pad:x+pad].sum()

    output -= np.min(output)

    return 255 - (output / np.max(output)) * 255
```

However, looping over the input image and taking the sum around a point seems to be very slow on larger images. Is there any convenient method to speed this up, or do I have to implement concurrency with threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are trying to get is the sum of a sliding window. you could do this with numpy by convolving the 2d array using a NxN matrix of 1s, but since you are using opencv i'll share the opencv method since it is faster.

`cv2.boxFilter(image, -1, (size,size), normalize=False, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)`

boxfilter convolves the image with a sizeXsize matrix of ones, which is usually normalized by dividing by size*size which gives you the average. We want the sum so we set normalize=False. borderType constant tells opencv to pad the edges of the image with a constant value (0 in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can use kernels and filter2D. What filter2D does it it takes your kernel (some 2d matrix of N x N size) and it multiplies element-wise at each position, then sums up the answer. To get the sum of all pixels in the area you can use a kernel filled with ones.

Note: I used borderType = BORDER_ISOLATED which means that pixels outside the image are assumed to be zero.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# create image
img = np.zeros((5, 5), np.float32);
img[:] = 10;
print("Image: ");
print(img);
print("-------------------");

# filter
size = 3; # use an odd number
kernel = np.ones((size, size), np.float32);

# sum
convolved = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernel, borderType = cv2.BORDER_ISOLATED);
print("Convolved: ");
print(convolved);
```

Here's the printed result:

```
Image:
[[10. 10. 10. 10. 10.]
 [10. 10. 10. 10. 10.]
 [10. 10. 10. 10. 10.]
 [10. 10. 10. 10. 10.]
 [10. 10. 10. 10. 10.]]
-------------------
Convolved:
[[40. 60. 60. 60. 40.]
 [60. 90. 90. 90. 60.]
 [60. 90. 90. 90. 60.]
 [60. 90. 90. 90. 60.]
 [40. 60. 60. 60. 40.]]
```

Edit: I tested the speed of filter2D and boxFilter to see if it really is as drastic a difference as O(N^2) vs O(1). There is no difference in growth factor when measured against image size or number of iterations, however Yves is correct when it comes to kernel size.

Here's the code I used to test:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

# tweakables
kernel_size = 300;
img_size = 1000;
iters = 500;

# create image
img = np.zeros((img_size, img_size), np.float32);
img[:] = 10;

# create kernel
kernel = np.ones((kernel_size, kernel_size), np.float32);

# convolve with filter2D
start = time.time();
for a in range(iters):
    convolved = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernel, borderType = cv2.BORDER_ISOLATED);
end = time.time();
print("Filter2D: " + str(end - start));

# convolve with box filter
dst = np.copy(img);
start = time.time();
for a in range(iters):
    cv2.boxFilter(img, 0, (kernel_size,kernel_size), dst, (-1,-1), False, cv2.BORDER_ISOLATED);
end = time.time();
print("BoxFilter: " + str(end - start));

# kernel_size = 3, img_size = 1000, iters = 500:
# 1.10 seconds with filter2D
# 1.18 seconds with boxFilter

# kernel_size = 3, img_size = 2000, iters = 500: 
# 4.80 seconds with filter2D
# 5.07 seconds with boxFilter

# kernel_size = 3, img_size = 1000, iters = 5000:
# 11.13 seconds with filter2D
# 11.41 seconds with boxFilter

# kernel_size = 30, img_size = 1000, iters = 500:
# 10.52 seconds with filter2D
# 1.63 seconds with boxFilter

# kernel_size = 60, img_size = 1000, iters = 500:
# 13.09 seconds with filter2D
# 1.64 seconds with boxFilter

# kernel_size = 300, img_size = 1000, iters = 500:
# 28.01 seconds with filter2D
# 2.43 seconds with boxFilter
```

Comment: This convolution is much slower than a true box filter (see Ta946's answer). O(N²) vs. O(1) per pixel.

Comment: are you sure? i was under the impression filter2d is faster because boxFilter is just a wrapper function ontop of filter2d. it could be faster if they have implented optimizations since its a more restricted method?

Comment: I can confirm that this method took 185ms, compared to boxFilter which took only 21ms. Still a very useful answer though.

Comment: It would surprise me a lot if they had a very different implementation for convolution under the hood.

Comment: I think i was mistaken, boxFilter might actually be a wrapper of sepFilter2D which is why it would be faster than filter2D because they convolve 2 1xsize kernel (1 for row, 1 for column) as a boxFilter is seperable which is faster than a sizexsize kernel used by filter2D